# JS Convert big (larger than 53 bits) number to string

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm having a rest service, which responds with JSON. One of the JSON's property contains a too large integer, and I want to get it as string before javascript corrupts it. Is it even possible? I tried to intercept every response with angular's HTTP Interceptor and parse the json, but no success. Here's my code.:

```
private parseJson(res: HttpResponse<string>): HttpResponse<any> {
    // body is string here
    let body: string = res.body;
    if (typeof body === 'string') {
       body = (body === '') ? null : JSON.parse(body, (key: any, value: any) => this.convertIdToString(key, value));
    }
return res.clone({body});

}

private convertIdToString(key, value): any {
    if (key === 'id' && typeof value !== 'string') {
      return value + '';
    }
    return value;
}
```

Example json (rest service MUST respond with integer for other applications, we cant modify it):

```
[{"id":10555555552168198656,"name":"something"}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you an example of the JSON your trying to decode?

Comment: Added example json (ofc its more complex, but for the purpose its fine).

Comment: You have to fix it before the JSON serialization happens.

Comment: I tried to do it with the reviver parameter of JSON.parse, how can I do it even earlier?

Comment: fetch it as a string, do a regexp on it, than parse it?

Comment: i have never encountered this problem, js should be able to handle that number you provided as an example. however if this is an issue, if u think about it logically, the hook for JSON.parse will be too late. the "value" in your code snippet is already the parsed number, which will crash. so you will probably have to write your own JSON.parse which handles this extra behavior whilst parsing the json string.

Comment: actually i have to admit i like the answer of @epascarello
work with string replace and regex first, put some quotation marks around the id and JSON.parse it afterwards. probably easier than a custom JSON.parse :)

Comment: Yea, I'll use string replace, thanks, but I'm not that great in regexp. Could someone provide that one line please, if it's not a big ask? :D

Comment: `a.replace(/("id":)(\d*)/g, '$1"$2"')`

Comment: It worked! Thank you guys.

Comment: It is always suspicious when an `id` is a 20-digit "number". Are you really going to do maths with it, or is it really a continuous index into an array storing more than ten quintillion elements? Because these are the use cases for numbers. Without further intent, a sequence of characters is a string, even if those characters happen to be digits.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try overwriting the JSON attribute for parse and then setting it back when the request is complete. Just be careful nothing else is using it in the meantime lol.

```
var oldparse = JSON.parse;
JSON.parse = function(value){
    //...do whatever you want
    oldparse(value);
}

//run your request
.then((result)=>{
    // do more stuff
    JSON.parse = oldparse;
}
```

There are probably cleaner ways to do this, but this is a simple example.

Comment: this code provides no utility, but plain complexity. essentially, if you put the "do whatever you want" part in front of your JSON.parse call in the first place, you accomplish the exact same behavior without overwriting anything by just one line of code ;)